# NGINX/uWSGI reverse proxy 502 Bad Gateway under load

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm using NGINX as a reverse proxy for a uWSGI server running a Flask app. Most requests are handled successfully but after about under load testing at 500 concurrent connections, some requests (but not all!) are dropped with a 502 Bad Gateway error.

According to the error log, it seems as though NGINX has trouble sending the connection through to uWSGI. I don't know why this fails, however, as I am easily running 100 uWSGI processes, each of which have a listen backlog of 300.

I've adjusted my net.core.somaxconn to 4096. My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
    user www-data;
    worker_processes auto;
    pid /run/nginx.pid;
    include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
    worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

    events {
        worker_connections 65535;
        multi_accept on;
    }

    http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    }
```

My sites-available config looks like this (with the real url replaced with myservice.com):

```
server {
server_name myservice.com www.myservice.com;
client_header_buffer_size 64k;
large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;

location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/ubuntu/api_master/api.sock;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
}

listen 443 ssl backlog=65535; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myservice.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myservice.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}
server {
if ($host = www.myservice.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


if ($host = myservice.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name myservice.com www.myservice.com;
return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated! It would be great if I could get to 4,096+ concurrent connections on this server; I'm sure the hardware can handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Turns out this was an issue with uWSGI, not NGINX. My incorrect assumption was that the listen backlog was per *process*, as opposed to in aggregate, and increasing that limit resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you first try multiplying net.core.somaxconn value by 4 then see if things get better. Otherwise, i'd suspect the `multi_accept on;` !